# How to change shortcuts for moving windows to the screen edges?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 under gnome-shell. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>KP_Left</kbd>, the active window moves to the left edge of the screen, likewise for right, up, and down. <kbd>KP_5</kbd> maximises/restores the window. (Fascinatingly, moving the window to the left or right at the same time moves it down a bit each time.)

I don't like that, as it interferes with certain Eclipse shortcuts, but I can't find a place to change these settings. In gconf-editor, I navigated to `/apps/metacity/window_keybindings` and found that `move_to_side_e` was set to <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>KP_Left</kbd>, and so on. I changed all these to disabled, to no avail (I tried logging out an in again.)

How can I change these shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

I just came here looking for this in GNOME 3.14, and you can simply change it in Settings (click in the top right-hand corner, and then the tools icon) by going to Keyboard, then the tab "Shortcuts", on the left-hand side click "Windows" (since we're talking keyboard shortcuts to manage windows) and set them for "View split on left" and "View split on right". Same for "Maximize window".

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at **Put plugin** in **CompizConfigSettingsManager**, "Bindings" tab, "Put within viewport" section.

Comment: compiz won't work with gnome-shell